# Why this is off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[How to handle business information about a contractor, I have from personal experience?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/97187/26185) Is put on hold as having no goal. I don't get how this can be taken as such.

I explain a situation, I explain what bothers me, I explain the options I have and ask for which of this options I should take as a professional.

Why thats not a given goal?

Comment: Is it just that you personally don't want to work with them or are you trying to get them removed as consultants? Can they continue being consultants without you directly working with them?

Comment: @Dukeling: Well personally I want neither to work with them nor that they stay as consultants. But from a professional point of view, I simply don't know what I should want to. And thats why I made that post. I need advise what would professionally reasonable without gooing too far due to the bias I have to them. To the latter, no they can't make the job without getting in contact with me.

Comment: The general phrasing of "should I do option A, B or C" as well as "what should I do?" tends to draw undeserved close votes, and "should I try to remain professional" is not really an appropriate question. I took a stab at editing it (also reducing the post down to its core) - feel free to update or revert it if you feel this deviates from your original intention. But **you still need a goal** - edit your question and state whether (1) you want to get them removed, (2) you want to avoid working with them (if possible), or (3) you want to bring this to light just to protect yourself.

Comment: @Dukeling: Thanks for the edit at first. its well broken down and just contained some misunderstandings, which I think after I edited your changes will be even more clear now. For my goals, my goal is it to simply inform my superiors about what I found out and the fact that there are bias that might cause trouble. But I want to do this without appearing unprofessional or making the impression influencing the managements decision to my favor. Since neither of the 2 is what I'm aiming for. I just know her and know that she probably won't stay professional. If I'm wrong, all is fine for me.

Comment: I added those details to your post as well. It seems fine now from my point of view and I voted to reopen, we'll see if others agree.